# Нужна многострочность в выпадающем списке, а именно: <br> внутри <option> select'а

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dropdown

Собственно, хотелось бы написать примерно так:

```
<select>
<option>Brain Reavis<br /><span>brian@thirdroute.com</span></option>
...
...
</select>
```

и получить картинку вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

естественно я понимаю что средствами HTML это не возможно, речь конечно же идет об имитации select'a средствами JavaScript.

Comment: Ну, да, нативным HTML, afaik - невозможно. Создать блок, который разбит на подблоки(странное слово), в которых указана информация в необходимом формате. В принципе из JS там будет только триггер на клик, который передал бы значение в поле инпута, остальное решаемо через css.

Comment: не хочу велосипед придумывать, готовое бы решение

Comment: В jquery ui вроде как раз есть такой "компонент".  https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

Comment: ну так гуглим например `custom select box template`. А вообще, велосипед не всегда есть плохо. Либо просто гуглим ui template весь готовый, берем оттуда селект

Comment: Делюсь с вами тремя ресурсами, на которые ориентировался при разработке собственного select: 1. [Custom Drop-Down List Styling](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/). 2. [Styling Drop Down Boxes with jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/). 3. [Styling Dark Select Dropdown With Dropkick.js](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/styling-dark-select-dropdown-with-dropkick-js/).

Answer (score 1):

Все почему-то привыкли, что для верстки раскрывающихся списков в `html` есть только `<select>` и `<option>`. Однако их почти невозможно стилизовать. В `html5` появились новые элементы - `<details>` и `<summary>`. В отличии от обычного `<select>` в `<details>` можно делать раскрывающиеся списки со своей разметкой и легко их стилизовать.

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #333;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 640px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

details {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

summary {
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/* Style the summary when details box is open */
details[open] summary {
  background: #69c773;
  color: #333;
}

/* Custom Markers */
#custom-marker summary {
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#custom-marker summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

#custom-marker summary:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4621/treehouse-icon-sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#custom-marker[open] summary:before {
  background-position: -18px 0;
}


table {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Details and Summary Elements Demo</h1>
  
  <h2>Example #1: Order Information</h2>
  
  <!-- Specifying an 'open' attribute will make all the content visible when the page loads -->
  <details>
<summary>Order #24892105</summary>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Order Date</th>
    <td>30th May 2003</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Order Number</th>
    <td>#24892105</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Courier</th>
    <td>Buy N Large Postal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Shipping Address</th>
    <td>
      P. Sherman,<br>
      42 Wallaby Way,<br>
      Sydney,<br>
      Australia
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Billing Address</th>
    <td>
      P. Sherman,<br>
      42 Wallaby Way,<br>
      Sydney,<br>
      Australia
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </details>
</div>
```

А вот выбор элемента придется делать с применением JS. Делюсь с вами тремя ресурсами, на которые ориентировался при разработке собственного выпадающего списка:

1. [Custom Drop-Down List Styling](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/).
2. [Styling Drop Down Boxes with jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/).
3. [Styling Dark Select Dropdown With Dropkick.js](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/styling-dark-select-dropdown-with-dropkick-js/).